# C++ Specialization of a null template for a class

Tags: c++, quantlib

In QuantLib I found this piece of code :

```
//! specialization of null template for this class
    template <>
    class Null<Array> {
      public:
        Null() {}
        operator Array() const { return Array(); }
    };
```

Anyone knows what this is about? What is the purpose of this code? If you have ressources on the matter i'm also interested. Thank you

Comment: A named default value.

Comment: What do you don't understand ? specialization syntax ? purpose of that class in QuantLib context.

Comment: Both. I can guess that there's a a `Null` class defined somewhere, and here we initialize it with `Array` but i don't understand more that that. and yes in the context of quantlib what does this do?

Comment: After a quick look at the lib source, it seems they use a custom `Null` class to determine default values for arithmetic types (real and integer numbers). Then it seems they also define a `Null` specialization for their data structures (like `Array`)... for coherence maybe?

Comment: It's actually a good exercice if you want to get more experience with template specialization (QuantLib seems to use it quite a lot). Take a good look at the [Null class source code](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/053689252a9d4137d8ac47dbfb88717b0c369d35/ql/utilities/null.hpp) and then try to see in your debugger the defaults values of a `Null<int>` variable, then a `Null<double>`, a `Null<Rate>`... Let us know your impression and what new questions you're asking yourself. :)

Comment: @giant_teapot I checked the Null class source code. Indeed, for each specialization of Null with a type `T`, the overloaded operator `()` returns a contructed object `T` based on `FloatingPointNull<
                         boost::is_floating_point<T>::value>::nullValue()` expression, where the boost "function" checks if the type is a floating point and returns a `bool` while the `FloatingPointNull` class is specialized with `true` or `false` and has a `nullValue()` which returns a `QL_NULL_REAL` or `QL_NULL_INTEGER`

Answer (score 3):

The Null value is used to represent missing values.

For instance, when you get a QL::Real r you can easily check if it is a null value:

```
if(r == Null<Real>())
```

The specialization for the Array is extensively used as default value in functions taking an Array as optional argument.

Comment: Interesting how this is used to check for null value. Can you give an example of how this is used for a function that takes an Array as optional arguement? thank you

Answer (score 2):

> I can guess that there's a a `Null` class defined somewhere, and here we initialize it with `Array`.

Almost correct. There is a `Null` class [template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template) defined somewhere, with a type argument. And here we [specialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) the template so that whenever the template is instantiated with the `Array` type, this definition is used instead of the original definition.

As for what `Null` is used for, see the [documentation](http://quantlib.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.3.13/classQuantLib_1_1Null.html).

> template class providing a null value for a given type.

Comment: Do you know why the specialization is needed here? The primary version should be enough.

Comment: @songyuanyao I have zero experience with quantlib, but a quick glance at the header which defines `Null`, the primary version appears to be empty. Float and integer specializations return a max value for their respective types (defined in a macro in some other file), so those wouldn't work with default initialized version that this specialization has.

Comment: Default version seem only suitable for scalar arithmetic types: it simply defines default values depending on whether a type is a integer or a real (floating point) number. Then this default behavior would not work too well on their data structures like `Array`.

Comment: @user2079303 That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The answers by user2079303 and jimifiki are both correct.  I'm adding this answer just to provide a bit of context.

The `Null` class template is used to add, well, a null value similar to what `None` is in Python, and is used as a default argument when (for whatever reason) we want to detect that the caller has not passed a value, as opposed to explicitly passing a "null" value like 0.  If we were to write the code today, we'd probably go for `boost::optional` instead (soon to be `std::optional`) which gives a clearer semantics and an explicit `nil` object.  However, we're keeping `Null` to avoid breaking client code.

For arithmetic types, the thing works by providing a `Null` specialization that, when converted to a number, gives one which is very unlikely to have been passed as a legitimate value (at least in the context of the call); namely, the maximum available int or float depending on the type. For `Array`, this doesn't really apply: as you see, `Null<Array>()` converts to an empty `Array`, which the code can't distinguish from an empty `Array` instance passed explicitly.  However, one might argue that an empty array is a null value in its own right (i.e., by passing an empty array you're not passing any values, even if you're passing an `Array` instance) so that kind of works out; the same goes for the `Date` class, which has an empty state returned by its `Null` specialization.

Comment: Very clear! Thank you. Could you give a quick example of a function that takes an Array as optional arguement using the Null specialization? thank you

Comment: A quick search gives a bunch of header files in the `ql/legacy/libormarketmodels` folder.